# PostAsJsonAsync posts as text/html onto server and not as JSON

Tags: c#, php, json, visual-studio-2012, async-await

I'm trying to post a JSON string on a PHP page using Async methods as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test_http
{
    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/ABC/products.php");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // HTTP GET
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("products/1");
                Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>();
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t${1}\t{2}", product.Name, product.Price, product.Category);
                }

                // HTTP POST
                var gizmo = new Product() { Name = "Gizmo", Price = 100, Category = "Widget" };
                response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(client.BaseAddress, gizmo);
                Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Uri gizmoUrl = response.Headers.Location;

                    // HTTP PUT
                    gizmo.Price = 80;   // Update price
                    response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(gizmoUrl, gizmo);
                    Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                    // HTTP DELETE
                    response = await client.DeleteAsync(gizmoUrl);
                    Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get a 200 status OK for POST, PUT and DELETE operations on the console window. But the PHP page displays nothing being posted. 
PHP code:

```
<?php
$json = json_encode($_POST);   
var_dump(json_decode($json));

?>
```

I figured out that the content-type of data being being posted is shown as 'text/html' in the console instead of 'application/json' and hence the PHP is unable to recognise the POST. But i dont know what i'm doing wrong here. 
could someone please help out?

Comment: You'r encoding an decoding your post in the php file.... why?

Comment: i was just trying out different possibilities to get the JSON string. but basically, I am trying to do var_dump($_POST); in the PHP. But the output is always:  array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

1st, there is no need to use `json_encode` as you are already sending json.

Second, phps global `$_POST` will only be populated if you send key:value pairs. If you are sending json you should use the input stream:

```
<?php
var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```

Comment: I tried that, but its just giving me this on the PHP page:       NULL

Comment: @RevathySanthanam try without `json_decode` and report back the result: `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: it prints just this:    string(0) "" @Steve

Comment: @RevathySanthanam Hmm, then you are not sending any data. Unfortunatly i have not worked with `c#` a lot since `NET 4.0` so am not particularly familiar with `HttpClient`

Comment: but when i try to debug the code in c#, it shows me the values being posted with the HTTP status code 200. I am not sure why it's actually just NULL in PHP. @Steve

Comment: I see, but if you are familiar with the older version, then you could possibly help me with this question of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27984496/null-json-posted-onto-php-server-using-http-requests-from-c-sharp

Comment: Using .net 4's `webClient` class, working just fine: http://pastebin.com/pq2Mv6d5 Although looking at your linked question im not sure if the problem is your code, but rather how you are checking it